# how to add onchange event to "form" in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have form something as shown below and it contains various validation text box and filter select. 
Html:

```
<form dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="Form2" action="" method="">
</form>
```

And i am trying to connect a form for an onchange event to an entire form but it is not working i.e. if i change some value in filter select or validation text box the event shown below is not triggering?

can any one please help me in this regard?

```
var handle= dojo.connect(dijit.byId("Form2").domNode,'onchange',function()
{
    console.log("I am inside the form");
    dojo.disconnect(handle);
});
```

Comment: Are you tied to an old version of dojo ??

Comment: using 1.8 dojo version

Comment: Couldn't guess... you are using pre 1.7 syntax...

Comment: will this cause any problem; actually we started with 1.7 but moved to 1.8 recently.

Comment: Not now, but you'll get stuck at 1.9... also you won't be able to use AMD asynchronously.

Comment: we were all new to dojo and javascript hence chose the easiest way to meet high requirements and are facing the consequences now. we have all the code put into declarative way as it is rich in UI. will this cause any problem.

Comment: No, declarative is still supported.

Comment: you mean AMD style right? we have plans to move to it. Is there any way if I can add onchange event to a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only use dijit widgets inside your form, you can easily create an evented form that emits a custom event, like the following :

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo/_base/array", 
    "dojo/Evented", 
    "dijit/registry", 
    "dijit/form/Form"
], function(declare, array, Evented, registry, Form){
    return declare([Form, Evented], {
        postCreate : function() {
            var self = this;
            this.inherited(arguments);

            // When any of my children changes, I emit a custom "change" event
            array.forEach(registry.findWidgets(self.domNode), function(childWidget){
                childWidget.onChange = function(){ 
                    self.emit("change", self.get("value"));
                };
            });
        }
    });
});
```

See [dojo/Evented](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/Evented.html) documentation, and a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/nXb79/).

Comment: Thanks for the above code this is cool solution, however in my form I have two content pains i.e dojox content panes which i keep doing an href to an html hence there will be a change in widget always depending on some context.Can we build any solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help Philippe.I implemented the same way as shown above its working fine:-)